# How to fit textviews and buttons to all screen sizes in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Textviews and buttons get all messed up in a different android device. I want to design the app so that it supports all devices. Can anyone help?

Comment: Follow this **[Github Link](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)** for `height`, `width`, `margin`, `padding` use **`sdp`** and for a textsize use **`ssp`**

Comment: implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
 and ->implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
after-> android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest `ConstraintLayout` to design the views. Try to use the four (top, bottom, left/start, right/end) constraints properly and as much tightly as possible. You can use `0dp / match_constraint` while creating the layouts, use aspect ratio, barrier and guideline if needed. In short, think deeply about the uncommon use-cases of the view, the solution and make it of dynamic size while creating it.